# Send Keys to update cells referenced in Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, macos, reference

I have a hard coded formula in some cells that are only updated upon pressing enter in the cells.

I would like this macro to "click into the cell and press enter" to update the value and cause the formula to return a value.

I have two macros, one that updates one specific cell, and another that I want to update an array of cell references. For some reason, only the one cell macro works. Does anyone know why? I would like this to be potentially used across multiple sheets and multiple rows/columns

One Cell:

```
Private Sub One_Cell_Click()

Range("$D$3").Select
Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

End Sub
```

Multiple Cells

```
Private Sub All_Cells_Click()
Dim cellUpdates(0 To 3) As Variant
Dim cell As Variant

cellUpdates(0) = "$D$3"
cellUpdates(1) = "$D$4"
cellUpdates(2) = "$G$5"
cellUpdates(3) = "$Y$6"

For Each cell In cellUpdates

Range(cellUpdates(cell)).Select
Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried instead setting `cell.Formula = cell.Formula` or calling `cell.Calculate` ?

Comment: not sure what this means, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Private Sub All_Cells_Click()
    Dim cell As Variant
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("D3,D4,G5,Y6").Cells
        With cell
            .Formula = .Formula
            .Calculate
        End With
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything when you run it?

Comment: it clicks over each cell but does not update the values. The cells are currently worded as ex: "=D1+D2". The only way for the cell to calculate is by clicking into the cell and press enter. this is an .xlsm workbook

Comment: OK that's weird - calling Calculate on a range should cause it to update

Answer (score 0):

This first section worked below, however I am trying to have multiple cells in different rows/columns be in the array. The second part will only run in the column that is referenced as the first value in the array. (If column A, it will only go down column A until I=4, not moving to different columns and rows).

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim cellUpdates(0 To 4) As Variant
Dim i As Integer

cellUpdates(0) = "$D$2"
cellUpdates(1) = "$D$3"
cellUpdates(2) = "$D$4"
cellUpdates(3) = "$D$5"
cellUpdates(4) = "$D$6"

For i = 0 To UBound(cellUpdates)

Range(cellUpdates(cell)).Select
Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Next i
End Sub
```

Not working part:

```
Private Sub All_Cells_Click()
Dim cellUpdates(0 To 4) As Variant
Dim i As Integer

cellUpdates(0) = "$A$2"
cellUpdates(1) = "$B$3"
cellUpdates(2) = "$C$4"
cellUpdates(3) = "$D$5"
cellUpdates(4) = "$E$6"

For i = 0 To UBound(cellUpdates)

Range(cellUpdates(cell)).Select
Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Next i

End Sub
```